# mui-datatables hide column headers

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Using the [materialui-datatables](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mui-datatables) package, is there a way to toggle the column headers? I see examples for overriding the custom styling but can't find an option in the site api.

Examples are [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/gregnb/mui-datatables) in a sandbox.

My current table looks like this:

```
const columns = [
        {
            name: "Question",
            label: "",
            options: {
                someOptionToToggle: true
            },
        }, 
        {
            name: "Answer",
            label: ""        
        }
    ]; 
 const options = {
        filter: false,
        responsive: "scroll",
        download: false,
        sort: false,
        selectableRows: false,
        print: false,
        viewColumns: false,
        searchOpen: true,
        searchText: searchText,
        search: false,
        customSearchRender: () => null
    }; 
<MUIDataTable
      title={""}
      data={faqData}
      columns={columns}
      options={options}
/>
```

It would seem that the option `label` option would provide this if set to blank, but the header name remains.
I've tried various other attributes in the column options, is this possible?

Comment: You can add `customHeadRender: ()=>null` to each column in options

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova thanks, that did the trick. Feel free to add it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`customHeadRender` function is used to customise header, to remove it entirely you can return `null` from it: `options:{customHeadRender: ()=>null}`

Answer (score 7):

As of now, with latest MUI version you can make use of the `slots/slotsProps` to customize the DataGrid.

The `component/componentProps` is now deprecated.

More information: https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/components/#overriding-components

The `slots` props allows you to customize the column header where you can return `null` to hide it.

Example:

```
<DataGrid
  slots={{
    columnHeaders: () => null,
  }}
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

MUI Version 5.2.3

```js
import { DataGrid as MuiDataGrid } from "@mui/x-data-grid";

const DataGrid = styled(MuiDataGrid)(({ theme }) => ({
  "& .MuiDataGrid-columnHeaders": { display: "none" },
  "& .MuiDataGrid-virtualScroller": { marginTop: "0!important" },
}));

export default function DataTable() {
  return (
    <div style={{ width: "100%" }}>
      <DataGrid autoHeight rows={rows} columns={columns} />
    </div>
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

in latest version 5.17.9

```
<DataGrid
   components={{
     Header: () => null,
   }}
/>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: The original question was about the header, not the footer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `columnHeaderHeight` https://mui.com/x/api/data-grid/data-grid/#DataGrid-prop-columnHeaderHeight

Example:

```
<DataGridPro
  columnHeaderHeight={0}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can set `columnHeaderHeight` to `0`